# S3 files take very long time to load

Tags: laravel, performance, amazon-s3, optimization

When get file from s3 , file takes very long time to load.
i think storage 'has' function take time. how can i optimised this ?

```
   if(Storage::disk('s3')->has($value))
    {            
        $image = Storage::disk('s3')->url($value);
    }
```

Comment: You have to file configuration  in `config\filesystem.php` and use just related function in everywhre

Comment: @A.ANoman how can i optimised file load time ?